# Type definition for overlapping types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typing

I would like to create the type definition for a function that takes two objects of different type but with common set of keys:

```
function myFunc(left, right, keys) {
  // simplified:
  for (const key of keys) {
    console.log(key, left[key] === right[key])
  }

  return { left, right }
}

const left = {a: 1, b: 2}
const right = {b: 2, c: 3}
myFunc(left, right, ["b"])
```

This approach works, but changes the type of the returned `right` which bites me in the code after the function call:

```
function myFunc<
  Left,
  Keys extends keyof Left
>(
  left: Left,
  right: Pick<Left, Keys>,
  keys: Keys[],
): {
  left: Left
  right: Pick<Left, Keys>
} {
  // ...
}
```

I want the returned type to be the same:

```
function myFunc<
  Left,
  Right extends Pick<Left, Keys>,
  Keys extends keyof Left & keyof Right
>(
  left: Left,
  right: Right,
  keys: Keys[]
): { 
  left: Left
  right: Right
}  {
  // ...
}
```

However, now I get the complaint that the types `Left[Keys]` and `Right[Keys]` do not overlap. Which I don't fully get.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Known issue without solution https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25642#issuecomment-492394799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A weird solution but it seems to work in the simple example.

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQDwChEGIAyiApgB5SlgAmAzogAowQDW2ASgDSIAUrpVHGCIOiAGSIBQkUQCUAPi75CYilVoNmbbER79Bw0RKmHZi5YUQBpMpWr0+0o2MnPzClQV4AbUsCgALmIeACcYAHMACyDRHmk6YOsAbQBdOWCAb0Q-AOC9RHDo2LEAX1xMr0RgOFC+CAQ6KFNURCMEuURKqysGsDo4PwA6HzgIg1QeXKhk6VTEAF4lwsiY2cF0qvKq0NIoEFCkbOmw1eby7b6mnP9mha7EAENggEYeACNggCYeCGCAFkQpQA3Lgrs0ijFFg9Pogfog-ogAMw8GjBACsQNBuAA9DjEAB1WqsQK4NCYSC+W6nYo8ZKIADk7wZiHSoPJWCpARpMTpjOZPAZEBZbNwuPxAFFQqFasEACqoAAOpEZ2AULJgDDAcGajzodEiYEe7z8iCgcDNSpVDIARO8bYgAD6IG0QG0MoZkjCck4rWmIekMx4iuTs72U32QqB8hk0ENhikQLnRv28gOMgBe8dwQA)

```
function myFunc<
    L extends Pick<R, (keyof R & keyof L)>,
    R extends Pick<L, (keyof R & keyof L)>,
    K extends (keyof R & keyof L)>
    (left: L, right: R, keys: K[]): { left: L, right: R }
{
    for (const key of keys) {
        console.log(key, left[key] === right[key])
    }

    return { left, right }
}
```

```
const left = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 4 };
const right = { b: 2, c: 3, d: 5 };

// Work:
myFunc(left, right, [ 'b' ]);
myFunc(left, right, [ 'b', 'c' ]);

// Error: Type '<>' is not assignable to type '"b" | "c"'.
myFunc(left, right, [ 'a' ]);
myFunc(left, right, [ 'd' ]);
myFunc(left, right, [ 'z' ]);
```

However it does seem to have some problems if the types of the values corresponding to the overlapping keys don't match. Might be a tricky way to fix it.

Overall it might just be best to turn off type checking for that one `===` line if possible.